# Find if my Facebook account was accessed from a different location

Tags: facebook, security, notifications, login

I suspect that someone I know logged into my Facebook account, yet I have no tangible evidence. If so, the person certainly did it from a different country (as I suspect a particular person).

Is there a way to check it? I haven't received the notification about any suspicious logins yet (do those notifications still exist?)—is it possible I will in near future? Is there any other way to check my recent sessions (but not the active ones)?

Answer (score 2):

There is a small likelihood that the session gets listed under Active Sessions under Settings > Security. You will be able to see approximate city from where the account was accessed. [It is currently displaying three of my non-logged out sessions accessed few days ago.]

The login notifications feature is available at least on my account (in same Security section). Email and text message are the options provided there.